# how to make an excel cell to show today's date

Tags: excel, date

I was trying to make an excel cell print today's date like this

```
=DATE(2013,3,23)
```

But it only prints that date until some user changes the numbers.
So please help me!

Comment: You seem to understand how to print today's date using the `Date()` function. I suggest you can also use `Today()` function.  But it seems like your real question is: "How do I prevent a user from changing the value(s) in a cell(s)?"

Comment: No.. Not Really. What I am actually trying to do is for a cell to read today's date and check another cell whether the information is valid as in today.

Comment: Well then why don't you revise your question and explain what you *really* want?

Answer (score 1):

`=Today()`

This formula is dymanic and will *always* show the current date.

You could do this, or use the `Date()` formula, and then copy/paste values.

But even if you do this, the user can still "change the numbers" after the fact, so you can't avoid that unless you protect the sheet, or implement some sort of event-based macro to maintain the desired date.

Here is a simple macro that will always put today's date in Cell A1 no matter what the user does to it.  Place this in the Worksheet's code module.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 'This will only trigger the event if the cell A1 changes. You can modify this as needed.

Target.Value = DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), Day(Now()))


End Sub
```

Comment: See revision for a simple macro to maintain today's date in a specified cell on your worksheet.